# What would happen after service given but can't agree on payment method

Tags: contract-law, customer-service

What happens after someone gets a service and then is charged but cannot pay using any of the provided methods?

I came up with the question because I used a shipping company and it would seem they expect me to type out all my credit card information and send it to them in an email, which I don't think is very secure. Any suggestions? I was considering giving it to them over the phone as then I could be certain who I'm talking with.

Comment: Send them your credit card information  and be done with it - If you use VISA or MASTERCARD and some fraud happens on your account you simply charge it back (ie if there is no signature, risk goes to the Merchant).    Alternatively, ask them if they have a cellphone, send half the card info by SMS and half by email.   Giving credit card details over the phone is not substantially more secure then sending them through email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this requirement was not made before rendering the service, you are under no obligation to accept the term. You and the service provider must now find an agreeable method of payment. You still owe the provider but if you are compelled to pay then the provider will be compelled to be more accommodating in their allowed payment methods (cash, at least).

As a general rule, if you are providing a service for any significant amount of money, you should require payment up front or at least a deposit and payments at milestones. Especially if you're 7,000 miles away from your client and put *any* restrictions on method of payment.

Answer (score -1):

You can settle your debt in any manner which you can agree between you. Be this by credit card, cash or chickens.

Your objection to putting your credit card details in an unsecured email seems perfectly sensible. If they are willing to take your details by phone then your problem is solved. If they aren't then you must find some other method that is agreeable to both of you, for example, writing out your card details and snail mailing them.

Ultimately, you can always settle your debt by going to their place of business and giving them [legal tender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_tender); they cannot refuse to accept this (actually, they can but if they do it extinguishes the debt).

Comment: Suppose the vendor will *only* accept CC by unsecured email or tender delivered at their office -- which is 7,000 miles away. Upon whom does the burden of accomodation rest?

Comment: @user6726 and suppose pigs fly too. The law is a practical thing - it only deals with cases that would not be laughed out of court.

Comment: In other words, there's no actual legal principle, instead the judge would make a subjective decision based on his feeling about the matter. Is that about right? I was just trying to see if your answer referred to a legal principle, or was it just an attempt at a practical resolution.